# pyspark 2.4 cannot create table from sql command Hive support is required to CREATE Hive TABLE

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark 2.4 and I already enabled the HiveSupport:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("spark").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

but when I'm running:

```
spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE reporting.sport_ads AS

SELECT 
*
, 'Home' as HomeOrAway
, HomeTeam as TeamName
FROM adwords_ads_brand
UNION
SELECT 
*
, 'Away' as HomeOrAway
, AwayTeam as TeamName
FROM adwords_ads_brand
""")
```

I hit the error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Hive support is required to CREATE Hive TABLE (AS SELECT);;\n'CreateTable `reporting`.`sport_ads`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, ErrorIfExists\n+- Distinct\n   +- Union\n      :-
....
```

It doesn't make any sense to me, am I doing something wrong?

ps: I have to add that this code works very well in databricks and with Spark with Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Check the below config value in your **`pyspark`**

```
>>> spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.sql.catalogImplementation")
```

if the property value not set to **`hive`**.

---

Try passing the below conf in pyspark shell

```
--conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive
```

and run your code again.

**`UPDATE:`**

Create a **`dataframe`** out of union query:

```
val df = spark.sql("""SELECT 
*
, 'Home' as HomeOrAway
, HomeTeam as TeamName
FROM adwords_ads_brand
UNION
SELECT 
*
, 'Away' as HomeOrAway
, AwayTeam as TeamName
FROM adwords_ads_brand""")
```

Then save the dataframe as table using **`.saveAsTable`** function

```
df.format("<parquet,orc..etc>").saveAsTable("<table_name>")
```

Comment: it says "hive" :(

I have a feeling that it's the command "CREATE TABLE" that is odd

Comment: @JayCee,I tried similar command on my end and it works fine in `pyspark`. try to create a dataframe out of this `union` and then use **`df.saveAsTable("db.table")`**, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967186/cannot-create-table-with-spark-sql-hive-support-is-required-to-create-hive-tab

Comment: This worked! Actually it was another table badly encoded (.snappy.parquet was missing) and I applied the .format('parquet').saveAsTable and it worked like a charm.

Thanks a lot, feel free to modify your answer for me to validate it.

Comment: @JayCee, Great.. Please check out the `updated the answer` and validate it..!